# How do I create a Mac OS install hard drive from InstallESD.dmg

Tags: macos, hard-drive, install, dmg

I have the InstallESD.dmg file for Mac OS El Capitain, and external Hard Drive with more than 200 GB.
I have no idea how to burn the InstallESD.dmg into the hard drive because I tried to burn it but it's not bootable not working.

[image]

How do I accomplish this ?

Comment: You need InstallMacOSX.pkg which comes from InstallMacOSX.dmg. See https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206886.

Comment: If I remember correctly, InstallESD.dmg was all you needed to create an installer disc in Mac OS X v10.7 (Lion) and 10.8 (Mountain Lion). But starting in 10.9 (Mavericks) it takes more than that, and the installer app contains a [`createinstallmedia` tool that can put the pieces together for you](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372#create) (but you need the full installer app to use it).